# Using Elastic Search to retrieve tag contents and hyphenated words

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene, tags, elasticsearch-plugin

We have elastic search configured with a whitespace analyzer in our application. The words are tokenized on whitespace, so a name like *`<fantastic> project`* is indexed as

```
["<fantastic>", "project"]
```

and *ABC-123-def project* is indexed as

```
["ABC-123-def", "project"]
```

When we then search for ABC-* the expected project turns up. But, if we specifically search for `<fantastic>` it won't show up at all. It's as though Lucene/Elastic Search ignores any search term that includes angle brackets. However, we *can* search for `fantastic`, or `<*fantastic*` or `*fantastic*` and it finds it fine, even though the word is not indexed separately from the angle brackets.

The standard analyzer tokenizes on any non-alphanumeric character. *`<fantatsic>`* project is indexed as

```
["fantastic", "project"]
```

and *ABC-123-def* project is indexed as

```
["ABC", "123", "def", "project"]
```

This breaks the ability to search successfully using `ABC-123-*`. However, what we get with the standard analyzer is that someone can then specifically search for `<fantastic>` and it returns the desired results.

If instead of a standard analyzer we add a char_filter to the whitespace analyzer that filters out the angle brackets on tags, (replace `<(.*)>` with `$1`) it will be indexed thus:
*`<fantatsic> project`* is indexed as

```
["fantastic", "project"]
```

(no angle brackets).  And *ABC-123-def project* is indexed as

```
["ABC-123-def", "project"]
```

It looks promising, but we end up with the same results as for the plain whitespace analyzer: When we search specifically for `<fantastic>`, we get nothing, but `*fantastic*` works fine.

Can anyone out on Stack Overflow explain this weirdness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a tokenizer for special characters, see the following example

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1,
            "number_of_replicas" : 1
        },  
        "analysis" : {
            "filter" : {
                "custom_filter" : {
                    "type" : "word_delimiter",
                    "type_table": ["> => ALPHA", "< => ALPHA"]
                }   
            },
            "analyzer" : {
                "custom_analyzer" : {
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                    "filter" : ["lowercase", "custom_filter"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "my_type" : {
            "properties" : {
                "msg" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "analyzer" : "custom_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**<>** as ALPHA character causing the underlying word_delimiter to treat them as alphabetic characters.